# NAPI AsyncWorker: transform a pointer array to Napi::Array without using a big for?

Tags: c++, node.js

How are you? How can I transform a pointer to a Napi::Arrray without `for` or is it the fastest that is possible?

**Second question**: Transforming from the pointer to `Napi::Array` is `ȮnOk` in the worker thread or is that already on the main thread?

---

**First question**:I was able to solve it, but the problem is, that there is transformation, first I transform the `GPU ArrayFire array` to a `pointer`, then I have to create a `for` and then create the `Napi::Array`, for me it looks like not right. Is there a better solution? Can I use a `pointer` for a `Napi::Array` somehow???

**Second**: The `OnOk` method I have to do the transformation from `ArrayFire` to `Napi`. Is this on the main thread on the `OnOk` or is it still on the worker thread? Because I have to create 3000 transformation in the `OnOk` because the `Env()` was not available on the `Execute` method, only on the `OnOk` and I would not like to block the event loop...

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <arrayfire.h>

#include <napi.h>

#include "test.h"

using std::cout;
using std::vector;

using namespace af;
using namespace Napi;

#define POINTS 1000

class ArrayTestWorker : public Napi::AsyncWorker {

public:

    ArrayTestWorker(Napi::Function& callback) : Napi::AsyncWorker(callback) {

    }

    ~ArrayTestWorker() {}

    void Execute () {
        try {
           // int points = 200;
            x = randu(POINTS);
            y = randu(POINTS);
            z = randu(POINTS);

        } catch (af::exception& e) {
            Napi::AsyncWorker::SetError(e.what());
        }
    }

    void Transform(array& arr, Napi::Array& napiArr) {
        int count = arr.elements();
        float *host_a = arr.host<float>();

        cout << "elements: " << count << "\n";

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            cout << i << " - i , element: " << host_a[i] << "\n";
            napiArr[i] = host_a[i];
        }

        freeHost(host_a);
    }

    void OnOK() {
        Napi::HandleScope scope(Env());
        Napi::Object obj = Napi::Object::New(Env());

        Napi::Array xArray = Napi::Array::New(Env(), x.elements());
        Napi::Array yArray = Napi::Array::New(Env(), y.elements());
        Napi::Array zArray = Napi::Array::New(Env(), z.elements());

        Transform(x, xArray);
        Transform(y, yArray);
        Transform(z, zArray);

        obj.Set("x-length", x.elements());
        obj.Set("y-length", y.elements());
        obj.Set("z-length", z.elements());
        obj.Set("x", xArray);
        obj.Set("y", yArray);
        obj.Set("z", zArray);

        Callback().Call({Env().Undefined(), obj});
    }

private:
    array x;
    array y;
    array z;
};

Napi::Value ArrayFireTestAsync(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info) {
  //int points = info[0].As<Napi::Number>().Uint32Value();
  Napi::Function callback = info[0].As<Napi::Function>();
  ArrayTestWorker* testWorker = new ArrayTestWorker(callback);
  testWorker->Queue();
  return  info.Env().Undefined();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is no way to use a buffer as an array. I mean, it will be using an ArrayBuffer of float, but then you have to transform in NodeJs to convert from buffer to an array, so the fastest transformation is on pure C++ and using a loop.